# Drop-down menu not showing values using Thymeleaf

Tags: loops, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am creating a Spring Boot application using Maven and Thymeleaf.
I have a class Sessi0n, and another one Module. Sessi0n contains a list of Module (modules).

What I need to do, is to display in a template (using Thymeleaf) my Sessi0n(s), and populate a drop-down list with the module(s) affected to each sessi0n.

Here is my code:

```
    <select>
      <th:block th:each="module : ${sessi0n.modules}">
        <p th:text="${module.libelleModule}"></p>
     </th:block>
    </select>
```

I already searched on sites, read the documentation and looked throughout the solutions proposed by Stackoverflow. Even if there are some suggestions that may be suitable for my situation, I still can not figure it out, how to do, in order to make my code work (for each sessi0n that I choose, show me a drop-down menu with all the modules related for this sessi0n).

Many thanks guys, I am new to Thymeleaf, your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    @Entity
    public class Module {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String libelleModule;
    private int duree;
    //getters //setters



    @Entity
    public class Sessi0n {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String libelle;
    private Date dateDebut;
    private Date dateFin;
    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL);
    private List<Module> modules;
    //getter //setter
```

Comment: Can you please show your Controller class where you populate the model?

Answer (score 1):

Your `select` code should be something like this -

```
<select id="someId">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Choose one...</option>
    <option th:each="object : ${objectList}" 
            th:value="${object.id}" th:text="${object.name}">Options</option>
</select>
```

`Select` component works with `option` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<select>
    <option th:each="module : ${sessi0n.modules}" 
    th:text="${module.libelleModule}">
    </option>
</select>
```